# Participles: взорваться

Tags: participle

> Поиски осколков метеорита, взорвавшегося над территорией Челябинской области

What is the name of the participle for the word "взорвавшегося"?  Why isn't it shown here:
[взорваться — Викисловарь](http://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is shown there: ***взорва́вшийся***. It is nominative, in genitive it will be ***взорвавшегося***.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even cross my mind that was possible with participles.

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza Participles (причастия) combine properties of verbs and adjectives, and participles always agree with the noun, its gender and its case. Adverbial participles (деепричастия), on the contrary, do not agree with nouns because they combine properties of verbs and adverbs.